# How to add html table values to database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, jsrender

I have a table whose rows are dynamically added. The problem arises when im trying to send data in each row when the submit button is clicked. I have the following function so far:

My HTML table:

```
<form id="ObsForm" method="POST" action="saveObstacles.php">
<table style="width:100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th><th></th><th>Obstacle</th><th>Likelihood</th><th>Severity</th><th>Principal</th><th>RiskOfObstacle</th><th>ValueOfObstacle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="MyTable">
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div class="controls">
<button class="save">Save</button><button class="addRow">Add Obstacle</button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"> <!-- value="submit" id="submit"> -->
<div id="saveWrapper">
<label>Saved Obstacles:</label></br>
<div id="savedDiv"></div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

The script for table:

```
<script class="rowItem" type="text/x-jsrender">
<tr>
<td><button class="remove">remove</button></td>
<td><input name="chkbox[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><textarea class="Obstacle" name="Obstacle[]" data-link="Obstacle" cols="20"></textarea></td>
<td>
<select class="Likelihood" name="Likelihood[]" data-link="Likelihood">
<option value="0.12">Low</option><option value="0.39">Medium</option><option value="0.49">High</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class="Severity" name="Severity[]" data-link="Severity">

<option value="0.12">Low</option><option value="0.39">Medium</option><option value="0.49">High</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input class="Principal" name="Principal[]" data-link="Principal" required="" placeholder="102.5" type="text" /></td>
<td><input class="ObsRisk" name="ObsRisk[]" data-link="ObsRisk" readonly="" type="text" /></td>
<td><input class="ObsValue" name="ObsValue[]" data-link="ObsValue" readonly="" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</script>
```

and obviously I have the addrow() function which works well. I have edited my previous function to the following:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var obsName = $("#Obstacle").val(); 
var likeli = $("#Likelihood").val();
var sever = $("#Severity").val();
var princ = $("#Principal").val();
var risk = $("#ObsRisk").val();
var value = $("#ObsValue").val();
var dataString = 'obsName='+Obstacle+'likeli='+Likelihood+'sever='+Severity+'princ='+Principal+'risk='+ObsRisk+'value='+ObsValue;
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
data:dataString,
url:'saveObstacles.php',
success:function(data) {
alert(data);
}
});
});
```

finally my php code looks like this:

```
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['user']['UserName'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO obstacles (ObstacleID, Principal, ObstacleDescription, Uncertainty, Severity, UserName, ComplianceID)VALUES (:ID, :principal, :obstacleDec, :likelihoodScale, :severityScale, :aUser, :compID)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['Obstacle']); $i++) {
$values = array(':ID'=>'',':principal'=>$_POST['Principal'][$i], ':obstacleDec'=>$_POST['Obstacle'][$i],':likelihoodScale'=>$_POST['Likelihood'][$i], ':severityScale'=>$_POST['Severity'][$i], ':aUser'=>$user, ':compID'=>'');
//var_dump($values);
try{
$result= $stmt->execute($values);}catch(PDOException $ex){
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());}
}

header("Location: obstacles.php");
die("Redirecting to obstacles.php");
```

?>

I would like all the data in each row to be saved to the database when the submit button is clicked but that is not working at the moment. I am still struggling to understand how ajax works so if you could kindly help out. thanks.

Comment: Why would an event be fired? You haven't registered any event handlers.

Comment: What does your save.php script look like? I also need to see where the  function is bounded. You should try to see if console.log("Hello"); works in the function to make sure you are getting to your function in the first place. Basically you need to debug from the button click on upwards. if you see a js error you will probably see $ is not defined. Sorry I cant help you fully you need to provide more information.

Comment: where is this function being called? What troubleshooting steps have you taken? Really need to try harder at providing more details when asking questions

Comment: Please check the ammendments made and see if you need anymore details! thanks

Comment: you should really indent your code.

Comment: sure.. i just thought thats not the main issue here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. I changed the jquery/ajax function to the following:

```
$('.save').click(function (e) {
var obdata = JSON.stringify(obstacles);    
var ops = $('.options :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'saveObstacles.php',
        data: {"obstacles": obdata, "options": ops},    // json data to server
        success: function(d) {
            console.log(d);    // do something on success
            alert("Data Saved! Now you can get ..");
            //$('#savedDiv').html(d);
            $('#savedDiv').html(JSON.stringify(obstacles));
        }
});
```

});

and then I could get the data in my php file like this:

```
<?php
require("common.php");
error_reporting(0);
$json_arr = json_decode($_POST['obstacles'], true);
var_dump($json_arr);
echo "First name in json is:". $json_arr[0]['Obstacle'];
?>
```